# Removing or Subtracting Facet Field Count in Solr/Lucene

Tags: solr, count, lucene, indexing, facet

In solr I'm using facet_fields and termvectors to store and compute some language analysis, which will yield the most used words in my index.

I am having a problem now because:

- I had previously used replace chars and replace patterns, charfilters and filters, at index time to replace "EP" by "European Parliament". At that point, it increased the facet_field count for "European Parliament".

  - Now I have already deleted the document which generated the "European Parliament" and still that facet_field.count will not subtract!! Is there a way to either remove a facet_field or to subtract its count manually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 'Optimize' for that core to physically get rid of deleted documents

Term vector numbers include information of deleted documents as well.